# Get the thumbnail contents in a variable instead of saving on a file

Tags: php, ffmpeg

I need to create a thumbnail from a remote video URL but I do not want this thumbnail to be stored. I need to get it in a variable so I can save it later.

```
shell_exec("ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -s 150x150 -ss 00:00:00.750 -vframes 1 output.png");
```

How to I get the output.png instead of saving it as a file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could combining the following commands:

- `ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -s 150x150 -ss 00:00:00.750 -vframes 1 output.png -hide_banner -loglevel panic`
- This will make the output from `ffmpeg` as quiet as possible
- `cat output.png`
- Print the file contents to the console (and be returned by `shell_exec`)
- `rm output.png`
- Delete the file

to the following:

```
shell_exec("ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -s 150x150 -ss 00:00:00.750 -vframes 1 output.png -hide_banner -loglevel panic; cat output.png; rm output.png");
```

I'm not aware of any method to get ffmpeg to dump data directly without placing it into a file.

Hope this helps.